# Wrong speed and course from CLLocationManager when using kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation

Tags: ios, gps, core-location

Sometimes I get strange values for speed and course in didUpdateToLocation. This probably started when I changed the desiredAccuracy setting from kCLLocationAccuracyBest to kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation. The course could drift up to 90 degrees. Another problem is that the speed sometimes is set to 0 if the device is perfectly still(even if the boat/car is moving). I don't know if the problems are related or not.

I can confirm this behavior on several devices both ipad2 and ipad3.

Has anyone experienced anything similar?

/Martin

Answer (score 1):

I just tried an experiment with this, using a new iPhone with iOS 7.02.  I could not replicate  your issues.  Specifically, I was using the delegate method didUpdateLocations,

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

since didUpdateToLocation has been deprecated since iOS6. I don't know that the locations array is any different than the newLocation returned in the deprecated method.

I tried it both walking and driving, and got good results.  Yes, the course will bounce around, and is not as instantly accurate as the compass heading, but I didn't see it vary as much as 90 degrees while moving, nor did I see speed at zero.

If you have poor signal from GPS or even WiFi, or if you are moving then you can see that kind of behavior.  Maybe this is not the sort of answer you were hoping for, but as it's been over a month, I thought I'd related my experience even though it does not confirm yours.

I could post a code snippet if that would be helpful.